# ORA-00936: missing expression when filling dataset to OracleDataAdapter

Tags: c#, database, oracle

I'm using this kind of code for MySQL, SQL Server and Oracle. For MySQL and SQL Server, it works just fine. When it comes to Oracle an "ORA-00936" exception is thrown when executing `adapter.Fill(dataset);`. Does someone have a clue why this is happening?

The error message is

> ORA-00936: missing expression when filling dataset to OracleDataAdapter

My SQL query is:

```
sqlQuery: "SELECT * FROM \"DWSYS\" WHERE NOT FCVERSION=@Version"
```

The C# code is:

```
public class OutputOracleQuery : IWriteSQLQuery
{
    private static readonly ILogger logger = LoggerFactory.Create(typeof(OutputOracleQuery));
    HelperEnvironmentVariable GetEnvironmentVariable = new HelperEnvironmentVariable();

    public DataSet GetData(string DBUser, string DBUserPassword, string sqlQuery, string databaseName, Version version)
    {
        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" + GetEnvironmentVariable.MachineName + ")(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))); User Id=" + DBUser + ";Password=" + DBUserPassword + ";"))
        {
            try
            {
                using (var command = new OracleCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Version", version.ToString());

                    OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);                     
                    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
                    adapter.Fill(dataset);

                    return dataset;
                }
            }
            catch (OracleException ex)
            {
                logger.Debug("Demanded Database action for the database " + "\"" + databaseName + "\"" + " could not be executed", ex);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: NB: `using` and `finally` together is unnecessary.

Comment: What is your `sqlQuery`? Can you please add in the post.

Comment: I totally agree :)

Comment: @Arulkumar "SELECT * FROM \"DWSYS\" WHERE NOT FCVERSION=@Version"

Comment: For Oracle the parameters are specified with a colon: `SELECT * FROM 'DWSYS' WHERE NOT FCVERSION= :Version`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [`OracleDataAdapter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracledataadapter.selectcommand?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_OracleClient_OracleDataAdapter_SelectCommand), you could use the following code.

In your `SqlQuery` instead of `@`, replace with `:`

so the `SqlQuery` will be

```
SELECT * FROM \"DWSYS\" WHERE NOT FCVERSION= :Version
```

and there is no `@` required in the parameter

```
 command.Parameters.Add("@Version", version.ToString());
```